# 1G colors in Windows with C++ MFC

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, colors, mfc

I am using Visual C++ 2019 with MFC, on Windows 10 Home Premium. The video mode is 3840*2160 40-60 Hz (AMD FreeSync) 30 bit/pixel: 10 bit / color part, 1 073 741 824 colors.

I can give colors with COLORREF = unsigned int (32 bits), what is interpreted as
(red | (green << 8) | (blue << 16)), this has only 16 777 216 colors. How can I give 1 073 741 824 colors? At now, 16M colors is converted to 1G colors. I need the method without conversion.

For example: CDC::SetPixel, FillSolidRect, SetTextColor, SetBkColor, Line, CPen/CBrush constructor, CBitmap, etc. Thank you.

(I want to save the time of conversion. For example, speed of key Page Up/Down in my own IDE is about 10 Hz, what is very slow. I generated the picture in the main memory (with CreateCompatibleBitmap, CreateCompatibleDC, BitBlt). When I drawed directly to the display, this was more slower. I tried SetBkMode OPAQUE and TRANSPARENT so, TextOut and DrawText so.)

Comment: Windows' GDI has no support for 10bit/channel color modes.

Comment: Each channel (Red, Green, Blue) of a GDI `COLORREF` supports only 8-bit (0-255) values, so a `COLORREF` supports up to 256x256x256 = 16,777,216 colors max. It simply can't go any higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDI does not support 10 bit color. You need to use DirectX.